# Sendgrid dynamic template PHP

Tags: php, api, sendgrid

I want to implement Sendgrid dynamic templates to a project i work on, and my problem is next:
here is some code that work, and I receive an email with substituted -forename-

```
    $content = new Content('text/html', '-forename- SOME TEXT');
    $mail->addContent($content);
    $mail->setSubject("TEST");
    $mail->addSubstitution('-forename-', 'SOME Name');
```

so my email body looks like this "SOME Name SOME TEXT"

Now I have the next piece of code that actually uses a template from sengrid that I created

```
        $mail->setTemplateId($template_id);
        $mail->addDynamicTemplateData("-forename-", 'SOME Name');
```

And text inside my template is next one 
" -forename- SOME TEXT "
So theoretically if template Id is correct I should receive on email the next body "SOME Name SOME TEXT" but instead I receive  -forename- SOME TEXT
I also tried

`$mail->addSubstitution('-forename-', 'SOME Name');`

but the result is the same

Email is sent with success but the variable is not substituted.

Sorry if I made any grammatical mistakes, hopefully my question make sense

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

you can add the Dynamic Template data in the following way:

```
$mail->addDynamicTemplateDatas( [
  'some_var'     => 'Some stuff',
  'template_data' => 'Data here'
] );
```

The function you have used will only iterate through the variables of your template.

Hope I could help you.